# Gitlab CI prepare environment: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-for-windows

I have created a windows image that I pushed to a custom registry.
The image builds without any error. It also runs perfectly fine on any machine using the command `docker run`.

I use a gitlab runner configured to use docker-windows, on a windows host.
The image also runs perfectly fine on the windows host when using the command `docker run` in a shell.

However, when gitlab CI triggers the pipeline, I get the following log containing an error :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.9.0 (d1f69508)
  on Test windows docker runner daSVobYW
Preparing the "docker-windows" executor 00:01
Using Docker executor with image someaddress:someport/windows_msvc2019_qt-desktop-6.2.3:v1.0.0 ...
Pulling docker image someaddress:someport/windows_msvc2019_qt-desktop-6.2.3:v1.0.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:XXX for someaddress:someport/windows_msvc2019_qt-desktop-6.2.3:v1.0.0 with digest someaddress:someport/windows_msvc2019_qt-desktop-6.2.3@sha256:XXX ...
Preparing environment
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 2f20866e4110118edc3274945d93d6138a16a67f9865d325e8b81c572ce08b96: Access denied. (exec.go:73:0s). Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

I looked a the pointed web page but didn't find any good answer to my issue.
Any idea ?

Here is my docker info output:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.1)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.3.3)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.17.0)

Server:
 Containers: 15
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 15
 Images: 5
 Server Version: 20.10.13
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
  Windows:
  LCOW:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: hyperv
 Kernel Version: 10.0 19044 (19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406)
 Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 2009 (OS Build 19044.1586)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 15.9GiB
 Name: RUNNERNAME
 ID: 35KO:UJAL:TZQ6:KA57:7Q3I:QTLO:YCTI:AR2Y:TIDC:K4UL:VYJ5:BPWR
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries: someaddress:someport
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

and the content of gitlab runner config file :

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  url = "someurl"
  token = "sometoken"
  executor = "docker-windows"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "someaddress:someport/windows_msvc2019_qt-desktop-6.2.3"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["c:\\cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem using Docker version 4.6.0 and above.
Try to install docker 4.5.1 from here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/ and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. You made my day. Have you reported the error to docker?

Comment: No, I don't know who's at fault, is it gitlab or docker.... I thought maybe I was doing something wrong, but it seems that I'm not the only one, so I guess I can report it. Since images work from console, I am more inclined to think that this should be reported to gitlab. I'll try to do that and post link to the issue here

Comment: Reported to gitlab https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28974

Comment: Issue fixed with docker v4.7.1

Comment: SauliusZ, when you say this is fixed with Docker v4.7.1, is that based something Docker have said?  I am having this problem with Docker 4.8.1 (78998) on my own PC.  I have installed Docker for Windows today, switched to  Windows containers and tried the command "Docker run hello-world".  I then get the "hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem" error like above.

Comment: @AntWaters This issue was related to gitlab. In your case you're trying to run image from console. And from console it was always working in my case